# Get list of cities that meet a high/low temperature range and precipitation

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

I am trying to use the OpenWeatherMap API to find a list of cities with a given precipitation and have average high/low temperatures within a given range. However, I am not sure if the OpenWeatherMap API can satisfy this requirement.

Is there an API that can return this information? If not, what would be the best way to obtain this information?

Comment: Well I don't think you can ask it to only return cities in a given temperature range, if that's what you're asking. You could ask for data on all the cities and then do the filtering in your own code.

Comment: That is what I'm going to default to, but there are other web-apps that have implemented similar features. I'm not sure if those apps accomplished this with some API or wrote their own code for it.